# How to add a native dll to the references of a C++ CLI project?

Tags: c++, reference, command-line-interface

I have a C# project that analyzes a managed dll and its references (using Assembly.Load()). However today I stumbled upon the following problem - a C++ cli project that depends on native dlls doesn't list them as references when its output DLL is loaded.

To picture what I'd like to end up with, I'll use another managed C++ dll that "references" native dlls when opened with ILSpy:

[image]

In the given example nmath_native_x64.dll & nmath_sf_x64.dll are unmanaged.

However the managed dll from the C++ cli project that I was talking about in the beginning doesn't list any of its native dependencies when loaded using Assembly.Load() or using ILSpy. Why? Is there an easy way to fix the project so that it contains them (provided that I have the source)?

I'm not a hardcore C++ guy and would be very grateful if you could provide more details or links/articles.

Comment: Why do you think that's a problem?  Are you sure that `nmath_native_x64.dll` and `nmath_sf_x64.dll` are pure unmanaged?

Comment: And are you more concerned with making your C++/CLI DLL show native dependencies as if they were managed references, or teaching your C# tool how to see native dependencies?

Comment: They are unmanaged. I don't think I'll have to use it for any other C++/CLI dll in the near future so I'd prefer the former as it also sounds easier to do (or am I wrong?).

Comment: Seeing native dependencies is a matter of parsing the PE header and reading the import table.  Not hard if you've dealt with binary file formats before.  For reconfiguring the assembly references, it would help to see `dumpbin /headers` output for the various DLLs in question (both reference and referrer, for both working and non-working cases).